# How to identify this MacOs menu bar application logo

Tags: menu-bar

Apologies if I'm asking this question in the wrong StackExchange community, please let me know if that is the case, so I can delete my question.

Since I couldn't identify this icon anywhere else, I turned here for help.

The icon that looks like a microsd card sketch on right side of headphone icon in MacOS menu bar has a timer next to it which increments every second like a regular clock.

I did a reverse image search on TinEye and Google Images for this but no luck. The resolution is too low for any matches.

Context:

I see this on another person's desktop share during Zoom calls.

Our manager (at my workplace we all use MacOS machines) started using this application during our team meetings and 1-on-1 calls. If you use Zoom's own screen recording, it warns the guests that it's being recorded. So I want to know if we're being secretly recorded.

I can't confront him since it's a sensitive time at the company and more layoffs might be on the horizon.

Your help would be appreciated if you recognize this icon or can suggest any other way I can identify it.

Thank you very much

[image: unknown application icon in menu bar]

Comment: I think it is indicating a VPN connection which has been active for 30m59s.

Comment: As per @Gilby’s suggestion, I searched “VPN Menubar icons” in google images and I can see the exact same icon shown above. So I think he is using a VPN. Btw, there are many ways to hide menu bar icons from settings in the specific app, to modifying Plists, to using software like Bartender App to hide menu bar icons. So, if you’re concerned about being recorded, maybe you should raise it with your HR as like a general concern and maybe they can send a reminder to the whole team that screen recording is prohibited?

Comment: Thank you both @AVelj and Gilby. AVelj's point about modifying icon made me have some doubts actually. We are not permitted to use any VPN other than what IT team installs, which is a different app and has a different logo, we had another employee terminated because of infringement and my manager knows about this termination issue, too. I guess we just have to be more careful at work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates an active VPN (virtual private network) along with the connection time. Here is an example image which I found the web:

[image: VPN example]

This one is without the optional connection time.

Comment: Thanks Gibby. That appears to be the same logo.

Comment: What's the coffee cup icon?

Comment: Caffeinated (or similar app).